# how to set the name of returned index from df.columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` in pandas. When I run `df.columns`,  `Index(['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'], dtype='object', name='NAME')` is returned. What's the `name` here, how can I update it. And it doesn't appear in other dataframes, how can I add it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `df.columns.name` to get and modify it.

Answer (score 1):

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd

data={'Col1': ['a','b','c'],'Col2': ['d','e','f'], 'Col3': ['g','h','i']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'])

#By df.columns.set_names()
df.columns=df.columns.set_names(['set_name_1'])
print(df.columns)
print(df)

#By df.columns.name
df.columns.name='set_name_2'
print(df.columns)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
Index(['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'], dtype='object', name='set_name_1')
set_name_1 Col1 Col2 Col3
0             a    d    g
1             b    e    h
2             c    f    i
Index(['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'], dtype='object', name='set_name_2')
set_name_2 Col1 Col2 Col3
0             a    d    g
1             b    e    h
2             c    f    i
```